# Add text to pdf using Excel -VBA

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I don't have much knowledge about VBA. 
But I have a problem which I think can be solved with VBA.

I have a PDF file of 400 pages. I have an excel with page numbers and some text. Now I want this text to be copy pasted (Add Text under drawing markup in PDF tools) in the PDF.

I can do it manually but it will take 3 to 4 days. so can anybody help me and make my work easier. I wanted to do this in Excel-VBA.

I have 2013 Excel and Acrobat xi Pro.

Comment: You have a problem which I think you are underestimating.

Comment: If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

- If the pdf has forms in it, you are of course able to fill them in a programmatic way.
- If your document does not contain forms you are not going to be able to solve this problem in a trivial manner.

Why, I hear you ask?

- PDF documents, despite their reputation are more like containers of instructions than they are a WYSIWYG format
- instructions are bundled in groups called "objects"
- objects can be compressed (DEFLATE) into streams
- objects are indexed so they can be re-used (this is called the xref)
- the index uses byte-offsets to get a grip on which object is where in the document

Now what would happen if you wanted to add a single character somewhere in the document

1. you would need to decode the streams to figure out where you're actually placing content
2. Once you've found the right stream, and you've inserted your character, you have also screwed up the xref table.
3. Nothing will work anymore